# <Angular 7> Testing a function present in angular component which in turn is making a service call

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I am working on writing a test case for my LoginComponent.ts in my Angular application.
Inside my component there is a loginUser() method which reads the username and password from the FormGroup if the FormGroup is valid, and then goes on to call an authenticate(username, password) method present inside my LoginService.ts class.

Now in my login.component.spec.ts file I am trying to make a spy object of LoginService and call the spy's authenticate() method.

Please find my classes below-

```
LoginComponent.ts
-----------------

res: any;
constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {}

loginUser() {
    if(formGroup.valid) {
        this.loginService.authenticate(formGroup.username, formGroup.password).subscribe((response) => {
            this.res = response;
        }
    }
}
```

```
LoginService.ts
---------------

constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
authenticate(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    //http call that returns logged in user's data
}
```

```
LoginComponent.spec.ts
----------------------

describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  let loginServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('LoginService', ['authenticate']);
.
.
.
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [//All Required Modules
      ],
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
      providers: [ { provide: LoginService, useValue: loginServiceSpy } ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
    
  }));


it('should login user with valid credentials', () => {

    const fakeData = {fake-data-object};
    loginServiceSpy.authenticate.and.returnValue(of(fakeData));

    const formData = {
      "username": "username",
      "password": "password"
    };

    component.form.setValue(formData);
    console.log(component.form.valid) //returns true - which means form is valid
    component.loginUser(); 

    expect(component.res).toBeEqual(fakeData);
```

Also, I have tried debugging by putting multiple console loggers in my loginUser() method, the flow goes in my loginUser() method successfully but does not go inside the authenticate().subscribe(...);

And my test case fails with the error that "Expected undefined to be equal {fake-data-object}

> Angular Version : 7
> Jasmine Version : ~2.99.1
> Karma Version : ~4.0.0

I tried writing a test case just for the LoginService and created the spy for http which worked perfectly fine but I have no clue now.

Comment: The code you provided lacks a lot of information, could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in an online editor like [Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)? For tests you can also use this [Angular testing skeleton](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mtxscj?file=src/testing/test-files.ts)

Comment: Sure thing, will try to create a small example in Stackblitz. Although this is pretty much what I am doing. If you can elaborate on what I am missing here then that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking this could be a case of early assertion. Can you try the following with your code?

```
loginUser() {
    if(formGroup.valid) {
        this.loginService.authenticate(formGroup.username, formGroup.password).subscribe((response) => {
            // !! Add this log
            console.log('1');
            this.res = response;
        }
    }
}
..... // In test file
component.loginUser(); 

console.log('2');
expect(component.res).toBeEqual(fakeData);
```

You should see 1 logged, then 2.

If you see 2 logged, and no 1 ever, there is most likely something wrong with your setup where it does not go inside of the `subscribe` block.

If you see 2 logged then 1, this could be an issue with early assertion and we can probably fix that with `fakeAsync/tick`.

```
// Add fakeAsync wrapper here
it('should login user with valid credentials', fakeAsync(() => {

    const fakeData = {fake-data-object};
    loginServiceSpy.authenticate.and.returnValue(of(fakeData));

    const formData = {
      "username": "username",
      "password": "password"
    };

    component.form.setValue(formData);
    console.log(component.form.valid) //returns true - which means form is valid
    component.loginUser(); 

    // Add tick() to make everything in the micro task queue to complete before proceeding
    tick();
    console.log('2');
    expect(component.res).toEqual(fakeData);
}));
```

Make sure you see 1 then 2 in the `fakeAsync/tick` way as well.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply! I have tried using fakeAsync/tick as well, I see '2' getting printed but '1' does not get printed in the console.

Comment: Seeing 2 get printed but 1 not printed means there is most likely something wrong with your setup. In the method do `console.log(formGroup.valid)` and make sure it is `true` so it goes inside of the `if` statement. The rest of the setup looks okay.

Comment: I already have checked the formGroup validity. It is coming as true. Even I am under the impression that there is something wrong with the setup but I have cross checked everything multiple times and not able to pinpoint any issue with the code.